# Infinitely many deformation equivalent Hodge diamonds II

Tags: dg.differential-geometry, at.algebraic-topology, gt.geometric-topology, complex-geometry, cv.complex-variables

Let $S$ be a connected smooth complex-analytic space. Let $\phi:X\to S$ be a proper holomorphic submersion with connected fibers. Can the fibers of $\phi$ have infinitely many distinct Hodge diamonds?

$S$ is necessarily not quasi-compact.